# HTML/CSS - inline block display and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I have a set of [nivo sliders](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). I wanted to attach a shadow to each one so I've created wrappers and absolutely positioned shadows:

```
<div class="nivo-wrapper">
   (my slider code here)
   <img src="shadow.png" class="nivo-shadow" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nivo-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    display: inline-block; /*inline block so it has the same width as slider */
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.nivo-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /* absolutely positioned 100% wide so fits its parent */
}
```

So I have a very nice set of sliders with shadows that automatically change width.

The problem is - every time I hover my slider - the slider below the one I hovered changes it's position ("jumps" around 10px above) and on mouseout it changes to it's "proper" position.

It stops, when I change nivo-shadows position to relative/static (but this way the shadow has wrong width).

I'd love to show you what happens, but I couldn't make Nivo slider working in jsfiddle (even after copy-pasting all .js & .css libraries).

Comment: Can I just ask why you're using an image shadow when you can create one using css?

Comment: @Luke Landwalker, I can create box shadows but not Photoshop like shadows (by they way I don't like box shadows too much yet, if there are many elements using this feature the whole website drastically slows down). I don't even mention IE compatibility. I'm just wondering why absolutely positioned element inside of a inline-block one does something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by photoshop like shadows? Cast shadows?

Comment: @Luke Landwalker, I mean more complex shadows eg. http://dribbble.com/system/users/2504/screenshots/24108/shot_1275643480.jpg?1297274559 :)

Comment: ohh =) and yea you're right it won't go on jsfiddle =/. Its hard to help you when you can't see whats going on

Answer (score 1):

without seeing it.. I'll say this:

You gotta check the CSS using FireBug to see what is causing the jump on :hover -- there must be something doing it.  It almost sounds as if you have the incorrect height for one of your slide containers.  Could you give .nivo-wrapper a height without messing up your design?

Also, have you tried using top:0 or bottom:0 for your shadow?  That seemed like it could effect it..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a css rule for links `.nivo-shadow:hover { position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100%; }` so once you'd hover it stays there...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have to correct the position and the block model of your image shadow, that is  a [Replaced Element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements), `inline` by default:

```
 .nivo-shadow {
    display:block; /*<--update here*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0; /*<--update here: you must declare it, or top */
    width: 100%; /* absolutely positioned 100% wide so fits its parent */
 }
```

In fact, one [absolute positioned](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) element is positioned according to the coordinates provided through the “top”, “left”, “right” or “bottom” properties.